# How do browsers(Firefox more specifically) know which cookies are tracking cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies, incognito-mode

I came accross to a situation where Firefox in incognito mode blocks some of the cookies on my site. More specifically google analytics cookies like _ga, _gid, ..etc. Searching in the internet I came across to this [article](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/browsers/incognito-browser/#:%7E:text=It%20also%20blocks%20tracking%20cookies%20by%20default.). So browsers like Firefox somehow identify these cookies as tracking. But how? How does it know which cookies are tracking and which not? I need to know this because next time I set cookies on my server I dont want them to be blocked by browsers.

Comment: Questions about general computing are off-topic for Stackoverflow. This might be on-topic for https://superuser.com/ … but the article you link to does explain how it determines what cookies to block!

Answer (score 0):

In context of the article it just means blocking reference links. For instance it blocks sending the referral information from, for instance Facebook, to other sites.

Other sites use the referral information to decide who to pay to get more traffic and stuff like that.

There's like 100 different versions of the idea of "tracking" though.

Like the article points out, your ISP always know every DNS search you do and every call to an IP so they always know ALLLL your traffic and are "tracking" it.

There's also "ad tracking" where all those google calls send out what the crawler says is on the page in order to create targeted ads and all that.

I think, based on what you wrote, you're just talking about tracking links which is just scrubbing the referral link part though.

You'd have to be more specific if that's not what you're looking at.